# Parsing HTML nested within XML file (using BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some data in an XML file that contains HTML in its `description` field.

For example, the data looks like:

```
<xml>
    <description>
        <body>
           HTML I want
        </body>
    </description
    <description>
        <body>
           - more data I want -
        </body>
    </description>
</xml>
```

So far, what I've come up with is this:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile, 'html.parser')
descContent = soup.find_all('description')
for i in descContent:
    bodies = i.find_all('body')
    # This will return an object of type 'ResultSet'
    for n in bodies:
        print n
        # Nothing prints here.
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong; when I enumerate the entries in `descContent` it shows the content I'm looking for; the tricky part is getting in to the nested entries for `<body>`. Thanks for looking!

EDIT: After further playing around, it seems that BeautifulSoup doesn't recognize that there is HTML in the `<description>` tag - it appears as just text, hence the problem. I'm thinking of saving the results as an HTML file and reparsing that, but not sure if that will work, as saving contains the literal strings for all the carriage returns and new lines...

Answer (score 0):

use xml parser in lxml
you can install lxml parser with 
pip install lxml

```
with open("file.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')

for description in soup.find_all('description'):
    for body in description.find_all('body'):
        print body.text.replace('-', '').replace('\n', '').lstrip(' ')
```

or u can just type

```
print body.text
```